Need to restart Flink Batch job on job restart
I have a flink streaming application. For validation, I need to reference few tables in my postgres Table. For this i use tableApi within the datastreaming application. Everything works fine on  the job start as the tables are all read and loaded. But since JDBC source in flink is a bounded source, the job status changes to Finished for the Table API source tasks.
Even after I restart the application, due to checkpointing (I guess) the batch job doesnt pull data from table at that point. I would like a mechanism to retrigger this batch sources . I was expecting this to work on a job restart, but apparently it doesnt. Do we have any setting that I can work with to not store state for the batch sources only ?
